DC offset on headphones output
I'm using this circuit as headphone output driver of a digital audio synthesizer that I'm building. The signal "DAC-OUT" is coming from the internal DAC of the microcontroller, and can reach up to 3.3V. The "DIGITAL-OUT" is coming from the microcontroller too, but it's just a variable pulse 0V to 3.3V. Both signals represents audio frequencies, but in a narrow bandwidth, not the whole 20Hz to 20KHz as you can guess by looking at the various filters.
The issue that I'm having are:

there is about 150mV DC offset on the output jack, when there is no signal present.
there is a loud pop when switching on and off the unit
the signal from the DAC-OUT is never fully attenuated by VOL-1 potentiometer, even at min, something is still audible. Instead everything is fine in the VOL-2 path.

I'm wondering if there is something wrong in the design (I apologize, I'm still a newbie), or if the values I've used for the coupling capacitors are too low. Also I'd like to note that I've used MLCC 0603 capacitors (X7R for 100nF/1uF and C0G for the lower values) and aluminium electrolytics for the two 330uF.
thank you

update: following you suggestions:

replace C35 and C36 with 100uF 3uA rated leakage capacitors, now the DC offset is only 15mV (the original caps were rated at about 450uA leakage in their datasheet). I still need to check if the frequency response has been affected using 100uF instead of 330uF.
connected R43 to its own voltage divider made by a pair of 10K and a 22uF bypass capacitor. This fixed the bleed


Is the circuit design your own? If not, can you edit the question to include cite the source the design was found.

Do you see 150mV DC when there is nothing connected or phones connected? That should not happen unless the electrolytic caps have 150uA leakage. Also why use the NE5532 with only 5V supply? Are you sure the DAC out does not leak via R43 to half-VDD and from there to pin 3 of NE5532?

check resistance from output pin to ground really is 1k. If it is, check the large series caps on the output C35/36 are open circuit to DC. If all this is OK, somewhere, something is putting DC on the output - you have a short somewhere.


there is about 150mV DC offset on the output jack, when there is no signal present.

This is due to leakage through the electrolytic capacitors. Use a low leakage type.

Additional comment thanks to DrMoishe Pippik:
Ordinary electrolytic capacitors leak DC if they have been reverse polarized by AC. The output needs non-polarized caps, unless there is a steady DC bias at least equal to peak audio voltage.
See:https://www.jakelectronics.com/blog/what-is-non-polarized-capacitor


there is a loud pop when switching on and off the unit

This is caused by the by the initial stabilization of the operating point. You have two choices for a solution:

Soft-start the 5V supply.
Disconnect the output until dc operating point is stable.


the signal from the DAC-OUT is never fully attenuated by VOL-1 potentiometer, even at min, something is still audible. Instead everything is fine in the VOL-2 path.

The DAC-input has a signal path along VCC/2 to the noninverting input of  (IC2-1 pin-3). This bypasses the volume control. The non-inverting gain is always larger than the inverting gain especially for a summing amplifier.
Although VCC/2 looks well bypassed, there is still enough signal getting through to be audible.
It is better to provide mid-point bias separately for each amplifier rather than use a single bias rail.

Ordinary electrolytic capacitors leak DC if they have been reverse polarized by AC. The output needs non-polarized caps, unless there is a steady DC bias at least equal to peak audio voltage. See https://www.jakelectronics.com/blog/what-is-non-polarized-capacitor

Good point @DrMoishePippik

thank you. How should I provide mid-point bias separately for each amplifier? Another pair of resistors + bypass caps as separate voltage divider?

Yes. Just one more comment. The Sallen-Key filter R44 is 60k. This is the Thevenin resistance RTh seen from its junction with R45 looking back towards the DAC including the bias network. So the actual value of R44 should be 60k-RTh. So R43 should be more like 600k to not influence the filter parameters.

Your output coupling capacitors are on the high side. Although the TI datasheet recommends low-ESR capacitors 'throughout', I suggest replacing them with low-leakage electrolytics, maybe 100uF.
Some low-ESR caps, particularly solid polymer types, have quite high leakage. Your 150mV suggests leakage of 150uA which is very high.
An ordinary polarized electrolytic will have a maximum leakage of 0.02CV or less than 10uA, and a low-leakage polarized electrolytic less than 1/10 of  that. Typical leakage will be much lower than that (after some time). Low leakage caps are not as commonly available but Nichicon has a good selection. If you can't find them, an ordinary (non-low ESR) aluminum electrolytic rated for at least 16V and 100uF will be much better than what you have.
Make sure you have the polarity right and the voltage rating is adequate. A reversed capacitor can leak quite a bit if the reverse voltage exceeds a volt or two.
